# How to make the "New Crafting Recipe Unlocked" text in the corner say "New Blueprint Synthesized" instead?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a Minecraft map thing (sort of like Skyblock but not really) and it is an entirely Warm Ocean Biome world. I want to make the text in the corner when you unlock a crafting recipe say "New Blueprint(s) Synthesized" instead of "New Recipe(s) Unlocked" as a Subnautica reference. I plan on using a custom resource pack and I am somewhat experienced in commands, but I don't want to use a datapack or mod unless necessary. I think custom leave/join messages in chat are customizable using a custom language or something? I saw a different message that the usual one in a YouTube video once but it might have been one of the built-in Easter Egg languages, idk.
I googled "How to change minecraft text," "How to change minecraft new recipe unlocked text," and similar variations but everything was about JSON formatting.
Any help is appreciated c:

[image: This is the text I mean]

This is what I mean by "New Recipe Unlocked" text btw

Edit: For clarity, I don't want to play the text-to-speech that the PDA says in Subnautica, I just want to change the on-screen text c:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible by using resource packs and changing the language file. The format of a resource pack is like so:

```
 Name of Pack
└ … folders with stuff in it you want to change (ex: lang, font, etc)
└  lang
  ├ … language files (ex: en_us.json, en_cn.json, etc)
  └  en_us.json
```

What you want to do in this case is have your language file contain the bits of text you wish to edit. In this case, you're probably going to want to edit the "recipe.toast.title" field and the "recipe.toast.description" fields to fit your needs. The contents of the language file (en_us.json) should be something along the lines of this:

```
{ 
  "recipe.toast.title": "New Blueprint has", 
  "recipe.toast.description": "been Synthesized"
}
```

When I only changed the title to the full text you requested, I ended up with this, where it clips off the page:

[image: Minecraft Recipe Toast Tab Clipping]

So I added the other line to the description and got this:
[image: Minecraft Recipe Toast Tab No Clipping]

Of course this formatting isn't excellent with the colors varying like that, but you can customize the colors of different words by including a formatting code, located [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes). The finalized file that I've ended up with is this, but you can use any combinations of formatting that you like:

```
{
  "recipe.toast.title": "§3New §3Blueprint §3has", 
  "recipe.toast.description": "§3been §3Synthesized"
}
```

Final image result!

[image: Minecraft Recipe Toast Tab No Clipping with Color]